# How to get multiGroup IEnumerable dynamically

Tags: winforms, linq

```
public class Customer
{
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public bool IsHasMoney { get; set; }
        public bool IsHasCar { get; set; }

        private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer
            {
                Country = "USA",
                City = "NY",
                Name = "John",
                Address = "Brooklin",
                IsHasMoney = true,
                IsHasCar = true
            },
            new Customer
            {
                Country = "USA",
                City = "NY",
                Name = "Piter",
                Address = "Brooklin",
                IsHasMoney = true,
                IsHasCar = true
            },
            new Customer
            {
                Country = "USA",
                City = "NY",
                Name = "Nicolas",
                Address = "Brooklin",
                IsHasMoney = true,
                IsHasCar = true
            },
            new Customer
            {
                Country = "Canada",
                City = "Torotonto",
                Name = "John",
                Address = "Brooklin",
                IsHasMoney = true,
                IsHasCar = true
            }
        };

        public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            return customers;
        }

        public string[] arr = new string[] { "Country", "Country", "Country", "Country", "Country" };
    }

    public class OrderCustomer
    {
        static Customer customer = new Customer();

        private void GetAllGroups(List<Customer> _list, string[] propNames)
        {
            _list = customer.GetAllCustomers();

            foreach (var item in propNames)
            {
                _list = _list.GroupBy(item)..GroupBy(item)..GroupBy(item);
            }
/*new SubGroup will group recursivelly*/
        }
}
```

How I think, with every new loop iteration I'm getting a new type as `IGroup<bla bla bla, Type>`

I have some list of objects, and I have a `string[] arr` names of customer properties.

I'd like to get all sub groups grouped by `arr[]` values.

I've tried to use dynamic Linq but something went wrong.

I need to get all SubGroups for sort in last SubGroup fron every one. I need to figure out how to solve it.

How to get it recursively and dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by sub group?

Comment: why are you setting _list in your loop?

Comment: Why do you have `..`? Can you post code that compiles? What do you expect for a result - nested `IGroup<keytype, IGroup<keytype, IGroup<keytype, ...>>>` or flattened one level `IGroup<last_keytype,...>`? How do you expect `List<Customer> _list` to hold groups?

Comment: Why is your `arr` set to a list of `"Country"`?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing your code to work (`customers` should be `static`, `arr` should have different property names) and improving `GetAllGroups` to return `IEnumerable<List<Customer>>`, you can write the following.

First, an extension method for recursive grouping with flattening:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TRecord>> GroupByMany<TKey,TRecord>(this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TRecord>> src, Func<TRecord,TKey> keyFn) =>
        src.SelectMany(g => g.GroupBy(r => keyFn(r)));
}
```

Next, an static method in `Customer` to create a `Func` to return a key:

```
public static Func<Customer, object> KeyLambda(string propName) {
    var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "c");
    var propInfo = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(propName);
    Expression body = Expression.Property(parm, propInfo);
    if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, object>>(body, parm);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

The fixed definition for `arr`:

```
public static string[] arr = new string[] { "Country", "City", "IsHasMoney" };
```

Finally, the working `GetAllGroups`:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<Customer>> GetAllGroups(string[] propNames) {
    var wlist = customer.GetAllCustomers().GroupBy(Customer.KeyLambda(propNames[0]));

    foreach (var item in propNames.Skip(1))
        wlist = wlist.GroupByMany(Customer.KeyLambda(item));

    return wlist.Select(cg => cg.ToList());
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var ans = OrderCustomer.GetAllGroups(Customer.arr);
```